# Assigning certain variables to array as key and value

Tags: php, html

i have this table which has around 5 columns in it

```
column1, user_id, column3, column4, user_exp
```

If i do a select query like this

```
$mat_sql = mysql_query(
 "SELECT * 
  FROM users 
  ORDER BY user_exp DESC LIMIT 10", $general);
```

How would i get only the `user_id` and `user_exp` into an array, with `user_id as the key` and `user_exp as the value`?

Thanks

Comment: have you considered use of some ORM such as DiBi, Doctrine, Kohana, NetORM, etc.. ? It greatly simplifies this kind of tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mat_sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_exp FROM users ORDER BY user_exp DESC LIMIT 10", $general);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mat_sql)) {
    $result['user_id'] = $row['user_exp'];
}
```